# Is there a viable way to stream games over wifi in Linux?

Tags: networking, streaming, games

I have a Linux desktop PC in my basement, which I tend to use to play more recent games, as it has a reasonably powerful, dedicated NVidia GPU. However, I am wondering if there is a viable way to stream such a game in Linux over wifi from the desktop to a less-powerful laptop elsewhere in the house?

I am aware of the networking capabilities of X, which allows you to run an application on one machine, but have it display and take input from a window running on another machine (which can be done, for example, using ssh tunneling). There are also remote-desktop technologies like VNC.

However, games running at 30+ FPS with a fairly high resolution would need a lot of bandwidth. I know Steam has a 'home streaming' system, which I believe it uses video compression technology to compress the video stream to improve performance. Can anything similar be done using freely-available Linux technology?

So, I guess the question boils down to whether you can 'forward' an X application to another machine, with some sort of audio/video compression? A full remote desktop would probably not be a good solution, as it would be wasting a lot of bandwidth on unnecessary DE stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Both X11 forwarding and VNC are ill advised for the task as they were never designed to forward fast changing full screen rich images. Please try using [Steam Remote Play](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3629-riav-1617) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; however, I am aware of Steam Remote Play. So, really I am asking whether a similar thing can be done with general Linux tools, without using Steam. I can edit my question, if you felt that wasn't clear. Personally, I am not a fan of Steam - I use [gog.com](https://www.gog.com/), as I don't like DRM. So, it sounds like the answer might be 'no'.

Comment: I haven't heard of similar implementations in Linux. Despite its fame there are a lot of areas in Linux where it doesn't offer any tools/software comparable to what is available for proprietary OSes like Windows and Mac OS X.